# Is there any possible way to hide breakpoint in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to hide breakpoints in Visual Studio Code?
I never use breakpoints, and I want to make my VS Code page bigger.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If I understand correctly, try unchecking Settings > Text Editor > Glyph Margin.

Answer (score 5):

The settings.json version of this is `"editor.glyphMargin": false`